.sqlproj getting error when database having multiple schema - Error SQL71501: Table: [schema].[table] has an unresolved reference to Schema [schema]]
i have SQL Server database, with objects defined under two schemas,

Schema 1 - dbo.
Schema 2 - pr.
Tables - dbo.person, dbo.orders, pr.person , pr.orders, pr.sales
SP= dbo.getpersons, dbo.getdata, pr. salesinfo.

when imported the data into .sqlproj for creation of dacpac and automated deployment.
always get compilation build errors mentioning that .

Error SQL71501: Table: [pr].[person] has an unresolved reference to
Schema [pr]
Error SQL71501: Table: [pr].[orders] has an unresolved reference to
Schema [pr]
Error SQL71501: Table: [pr].[sales] has an unresolved reference to
Schema [pr]

I have tried by importing the database using
schema/Objects, objects only,
and also, included the schema name in filename also project settings..
nothing helped out.. got same problem
tried in SQL server 2016, 2019, 2022 in sqlproject Target platform
localbox settings

icrosoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
Version 17.9.6
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.9.6+34728.123
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
Version 17.9.6
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.9.6+34728.123
SQL Server Data Tools 17.9.56.1

can you please guide me on how to resolve this error.
does SQL project will support multiple schemas?
if not, what are alternatives,

SSDT certainly supports multiple schemas. Does the project contain a file with the CREATE SCHEMA for the schema pr?

when I imported the database, the schema file was not created by default. I have added manually the schema file, post adding the file.. it worked. Thank you @MartinSmith
